# QGIS plugin builder puts icon in different toolbars depending on plugin template selected

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, toolbar

When building a plugin using the QGIS Plugin Builder plugin, if I select 'Tool button with dialog' as the template, then my plugin button will be placed in the Plugins toolbar in QGIS.

If I build the plugin boilerplate with the 'Tool button with dock widget' template, then the plugin icon is put in its own toolbar.

[image]

I have compared the code and cannot find how to change this. I would like to build a plugin with a dialog, but have the icon in its own toolbar.

Please let me know if there is a way to make my question more clear.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Plugin builder version 3.2.1 I found differences.
In case of **Tool button with dialog** in add_action function *addToolBarIcon* is used (line 148):

```
self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)
```

which "Add an icon to the plugins toolbar." (quote from QGIS API documentation).

In case of **Tool button with dock widget** a new toolbar is created in *__init__* function (line 68):

```
self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'test_dock')
self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'test_dock')
```

and in the *add_action* function the *action* is added to the toolbar of the plugin (line 154):

```
self.toolbar.addAction(action)
```

So if you would like to create a **Tool button with dialog** plug-in with its own toolbar, please add your own toolbar to QGIS GUI in the *__init__* function of your plug-in, for example after *self.menu = ...* (line 64)

```
self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'my_plugin')
self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'my_plugin')
```

Please replace *my_plugin* to the name of your plug-in.

Change the *self.iface.addToolBarIcon* call in *add_action* function (line 147) to

```
   if add_to_toolbar:
        self.toolbar.addAction(action)
```

I used the line numbers of the original generated code.

Comment: Great, thankyou for your clear help Zoltan. I had found the first part `self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'my_plugin')
self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'my_plugin')` but had missed the line `self.toolbar.addAction(action)`. In the **Tool button with dialog** template that line is `self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)`, which must add it to the Plugins toolbar. Thanks again very clear answer.